# Google Chrome. How to restore passwords from profile folder?

Tags: google-chrome, encryption, passwords

I have copy of one of my Google Chrome Profiles. After Windows reinstall I tried to create new profile and then replace the files. However when I check my passwords in settings there is nothing. I also tried to restore them with [chromepass](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html) and it shows me the saved login sites and usernames but the password field is empty. Any other ways to recover the passwords?

Comment: It seems that you never saved passwords...

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I saved them, and in the past, I recovered passwords in that way. Just after Windows reinstallation, it isn't working anymore, maybe is something from the encryption.

Comment: Have you restored the file `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data`?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, it's there and I can see the saved usernames in it.

Comment: But did you manually copy the file from the old profile, or did you let ChromePass do it?

Comment: First I tried to replace just the Login Data file, then replaced the whole folder and finally, I tried with ChromePass. Same results - it shows me only the usernames without the passwords.

Comment: Do your passwords do show up in [passwords.google.com](http://passwords.google.com/)? If they do, I suggest to disconnect your account in Settings and check the option *Also clear your history, bookmarks, settings, and other Chrome data stores on this device*. Chrome will autoclose or you may close it manually. Open Chrome again, click Settings, Turn on Sync, and enter your credentials.