# "Login Data" file in Chrome - retrieve logins/passwords/URL's

Tags: google-chrome, encryption, passwords, decryption

I accidentally cleaned my Chrome passwords with some 3rd party software (yes I know - Im  a genius!). I've never synced the passwords online. Still it seems that the data exists in "Login Data" file ( %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data ). The good thing is that Im still on this machine and windows profile so I have the credentials and key to decrypt files with CryptProtectData (that's what I understood from other topics). This was the major issue when other people had similar question - they didn't have access to their original Chrome and Windows profile where the "Login Data" file came from.

**a)** I can see plain text URL's and logins in **"Login Data" file**

**b)** I could recover small part of passwords with (DPAPI DataProtectionDecryptor v1.10) https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dpapi_data_decryptor.html (screenshots attached)

BUT - on one hand I have just logins and url's in large file (**"Login Data"**) on the other hand I decrypted few but not related to logins or URL's ...

I tried also other software:

**a)** DB Browser for SQLite (1 password retrieved because I added new pass not being aware that they were deleted) - so it's from "new" clean database

**b)** ChromePass v1.52
https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html

**c)** WebBrowserPassView v2.07
https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_password.html

The software also see only new password even when I try different settings.

Helpfull topics that Im not able to understand technically:

https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/extract-chrome-passwords-python

[How does Google Chrome store passwords?](https://superuser.com/questions/146742/how-does-google-chrome-store-passwords)

[Where are Google chrome passwords stored in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/718383/where-are-google-chrome-passwords-stored-in-windows/)

[Google Chrome. How to restore passwords from profile folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/1403936/google-chrome-how-to-restore-passwords-from-profile-folder)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300837/decrypt-master-password-of-windows-api-cryptprotectdata-presumably

***I've read other topics on this matter but still cannot figure it out (Im NOT a developer). I cannot code but I understand some of it. I don't have servers installed, Im not on linux so please try to not paste line of codes in python for the answer.***

Attached images:

[Lots of passwords in password decryptor failed to decrypt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxlqk.png)

[Even when it's decrypted I don't know what's the login and what's the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK15J.png)

[My DPAPI configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScV4D.png)

[I can see data in "Login Data" file but I have no idea how to extract them and connect with decrypted passwords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzNft.png)

Thank you in advance!
M.

Comment: You've linked a lot of questions, and based on the few I've read, they already answer you question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Google Chrome store passwords?](https://superuser.com/questions/146742/how-does-google-chrome-store-passwords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use This Tool: HackBrowserData

You can Recover your passwords using this tool:**HackBrowserData**

Hack-browser-data is an open-source tool that could help you decrypt data ( passwords|bookmarks|cookies|history ) from the browser. It supports the most popular browsers on the market and runs on Windows, macOS and Linux.
This will decrupt Your Passwords and will store them in a simple .CSV fil

> Statement: This tool is limited to security research only, and the user assumes all legal and related responsibilities arising from its use! The author assumes no legal responsibility!

#### Supported Browser

Windows

| Browser | Password | Cookie | Bookmark | History |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google Chrome | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| Google Chrome Beta | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| Firefox | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| Microsoft Edge | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| 360 Speed Browser | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| QQ Browser | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| Brave Browser | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| Opera Browser | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| OperaGX Browser | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| Vivaldi Browser | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| Internet Explorer | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ | ❌ |

### Download

[Windows-64bit](https://github.com/moonD4rk/HackBrowserData/releases/download/v0.3.2/hack-browser-data-v0.3.2-windows-64bit.zip)

### Run

You can double-click to run, or use command line.

Comment: But OP states login data was deleted, does the tool you recommend help in that scenario? And if so, how?